# Poll custom oid in opennms

Tags: monitoring, snmp, opennms

I am trying to poll custom oid i.e. 1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.8.1.100.2.x using opennms. 
I will get transaction per second from these counters. I want to create graph out of this. I tried many documents from google & opennms wiki but no luck ! Kindly help. Any link or document is most welcome. I know how to create graph but *snmp polling & populating .jrd files* is where I am stuck

Regards,
Vijay

Comment: Folks,I am currently reading following link for more clue "http://www.opennms.org/blog/?p=227"

Answer (score 0):

Try
`snmpget <host>`

to see if SNMP is working properly.  No response means SNMP problems.

Try

`snmpwalk 1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.8.1.100.2`

If you get no response, it means the oid is not available for some reason.  You'll need to go back to your implementation process to see where it didnt complete, etc.

If both commands return data, then your Opennms configuration is suspect.